# Not able to set value to Session on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using ashx handler to set session varibale and trying to check that on button click on page.
I debug the session then i observe that session is empty

Comment: on which event the ashx handler is called? please show relevant code

Comment: I am generating captcha image in ashx handler

Comment: could you show the code? I get that you pass the Image's text in session and compare with user input right?

Comment: context.Session("img_captcha") = drawString  'setting the captcha text 
i am getting session null on button click and i just realise that .Net version is 2.0 and i am implementing IRequiresSessionState interface you have any solution on that

Comment: Does it work when you are not debugging it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the IRequiresSessionState to the handler like this

VB.NET

```
Public Class CaptchaHandler
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

     Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
         'do work here
         ctx.Session("img_captcha") = drawString
     End Sub
```

---

C#

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class CaptchaHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        // do work here
        ctx.Session["img_captcha"] = drawString;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Yes i know that, i am getting session in my local matchine it works fine, i am getting error on server which is hosted on iis 7.5 and .NET 2.0

Comment: have you tried HttpContext.Current.Session("img_captcha")

Comment: Now that problem is solved i dont know why that error is getting thank you for helping me